# Web Config Transformation in Debug Mode using TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, web-config

I have successfully transform Web Config and App Config in Debug Mode using this [Tutorial](http://www.kongsli.net/nblog/2012/01/13/enabling-web-transforms-when-debugging-asp-net-apps/)
. File Web.config will change depending on current Build Configuration.

My question is, will this functionality be possible in TFS ?

In my current project, there are several developers and we are using TFS, therefore any files being changed by someone will be set as "Checked Out" and prevent others from "Checking In" (or "Checking Out", depending on Lock type).
My objective is to enable other devs change their web.config automatically depending on their current Build Configuration.

So, if that Web.config is changed automatically each time we build, will this by any chance hinder others from that Lock mechanism ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several days of experimenting, I've found that if we edit files outside of Visual Studio Environment, then TFS won't check-out the item.
Based on that behaviour, I concluded that it is safe to use transformation with TFS and it is just the exact solution for my problem. Now our team can freely switch their Connection String based on their current selected Configuration without having to check-out and then check-in their Web.Config.